# Conformal map example $ f(z)=e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, conformal-geometry

I an studying the example-1.

I understand $f(z)=e^z$ has a nonzero derivative at all points, hence it is everywhere conformal and locally $1-1$.

But I dont understand th part I underlined with yellow pencil. Please explain it. Thank you so much:)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=x+iy$, $f(z)=e^z$, so $e^{c+iy}=e^c(\cos y+i\sin y)$ assuming $x=c$ constant is a circle with radius $e^c$

and $e^{x+ic}=e^x(\cos c+i\sin c)$

The Modulus of  $f(z) = e^x,$ argument $f(z) = y.$

Horizontal lines in the cartesian plane have a constant $y$ value so the argument of the map of the horizontal line is also constant while the norm changes with $e^x$ so horizontal lines are mapped to rays with argument $y.$

vertical lines have a constant $x$ component so the map of vertical lines have a constant modulus so vertical lines get mapped to circles centered at the origin with radius $e^x$

Comment: Hmm.. It seems understandable for me. can you explain a little bit?

Comment: sure I am writing in detail

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Conformal maps preserve angles, it is their defining property. From wikipedia, "a conformal map is a function which preserves angles". So when an angle is mapped from the pre-image to the image, it is the same if the map is conformal at that point. If it is not conformal, the angle may change.